# i got 4 items in HashMap and want to get them stored in an array

Tags: java

I want to retrieve objects stored in **hashmap**, all objects are of same type and want to store them in an array. i tried plenty of things but still not successful:
**Holding is an interface implemented by abstract class AbstractHolding** and further **extended by** two classes **Book and Video** they also implemented the interface which is standard practise. i have stored the items using constructor of both video and book class and its shows the correct length and content while using debugging. i wrote this piece of code ...

```
public Holding[] getAllHoldings() {
        System.out.println(holdingMap.values().toArray().length);
        Holding[] holding = (Holding[])holdingMap.values().toArray();

        return holding;

    }
```

but getting
 [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Llms.model.Holding;

i dont understand when the stored objects are of type Holding then why this casting error occurring...

Comment: Why don't you use a `LinkedHashMap` ? Or you can use `List<Holding>`

Comment: show your definition of your `holdingMap`

Comment: guys it worked from the solution given in Answer thanks guys cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `holdingMap.values().toArray(new Holding[0]);` instead

the toArray(T[] a) method will use

```
java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), size)
```

to create array of type T,That's can safely cast to T[]

Comment: thanks man it worked could you please tell me what exactly wrong with the previous code and how this code worked...

Comment: The previous code ,what toArray() returns a Object[].class instance,and what you need is a Holding[].class instance,Type cast will certainly fail

Comment: i tried the same but couldn't understand the size why it is 0 like you gave 0 in new Holding[0];

Comment: check the source code AbstractCollection.toArray(T[] a),if a's capacity is not sufficient,a new T[] will be created of the exactly size